# How to update data in Mysql using "not equal" condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has a table named property_list, and a column named agent. for now there is a lot of name inside it.

```
$agent = array("Tony","Nava","Ceri","Van","Turker");
```

Many things happen lately, and most of them are out and we need to change their name to Property Agent in table "property_list", except agent named Ceri and Van.

i have try this Query but it apperantly changes all the agent list at the table

```
UPDATE property_list SET agent = "Property Agent" WHERE agent != "Ceri" OR agent != "Van";
```

am i do it wrong?, currently using mysql and php to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND instead of OR if you want to update all records except Ceri and Van

```
UPDATE property_list SET agent = "Property Agent" WHERE agent != "Ceri" AND agent != "Van";
```